# Multithreading on Windows Forms Unresponse Main Form

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms

I am trying to sort an array of 5 random integers in a listbox to ascending order. While creating a new thread and calling it separately, the form becomes unresponsive when I select the 'sort' button.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    const int iSize = 5;
    int[] iArray = new int[iSize];
    Random rnd = new Random();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    Thread th;

    private void btnGenerate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < iArray.Length; i++)
        {
            iArray[i] = rnd.Next(0, 5);
            lbxNumbers.Items.Add(iArray[i]);
        }
    }

    public void threadMethod()
    {
        bubbleSort(iArray);
        foreach(int item in iArray)
        {
            lbxNumbers.Items.Add(item);
        }

    }

    private void btnSort_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        th = new Thread(threadMethod);
        lblStatusUpdate.Text = "Sorting...";

    }

    private void btnClear_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lbxNumbers.Items.Clear();
    }

    public static void bubbleSort(int [] iArray)
    {
        bool isSorted = false;
        int lastUnsorted = iArray.Length - 1;
        while(!isSorted)
        {
            for(int i = 0; i < iArray.Length-1; i++)
            {
                if(iArray[i] > iArray[i+1])
                {
                    swap(iArray, i, i + 1);
                    isSorted = false;

                }

            }
        }
    }
    public static void swap(int [] iArray, int i, int j)
    {
        int tmp = iArray[i];
        iArray[i] = iArray[j];
        iArray[j] = tmp;
    }

}
```

I am uncertain where the thread actually kicks in. The listbox can generate the array immediately and clear it, but sort makes it freeze. I am also unsure whether I need to use the background worker tool on this form.

Comment: You create the thread, but I don't see that you ever start it... Either way you have a cross-threading problem.

Comment: Do not use Threads to update the UI; use [`async/await`](http://msdn.com/async).

Answer (score 0):

To expound on [Dour High Arch's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22437/dour-high-arch) comment.

**EDIT**

There are a couple of issues with your code.  UI updates can only be done on the UI thread.  You can accomplish this with the SychronizationContext or async/await handles it for you.  Also, your bubblesort was missing an exit condition for the while loop, so it would run forever.  The following demonstrates how this would work using async/await.

```
private async void btnSort_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lblStatusUpdate.Text = @"Sorting...";
    await Run();

}


public async Task Run()
{
    //This line runs asynchronously and keeps the UI responsive.
    await bubbleSort(iArray);

    //The remaining code runs on the UI thread
    foreach (int item in iArray)
    {
        lbxNumbers.Items.Add(item);
    }
}


public async Task bubbleSort(int[] iArray)
{
    await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        bool isSorted = false;
        while (!isSorted)
        {
            isSorted = true; //You were missing this to break out of the loop.
            for (int i = 0; i < iArray.Length - 1; i++)
            {
                if (iArray[i] > iArray[i + 1])
                {
                    swap(iArray, i, i + 1);
                    isSorted = false;

                }

            }
        }

    });
}
```

Comment: The whole point of using `await` in cases like this is to allow it to handle using the synchronization context *for* you, specifically so that you don't have to.  If you're going to do all of this by hand (which you shouldn't do), there's no reason to use `await` at all.   Your code is no different than if you'd have removed it entirely.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @Servy.  I adjusted my answer.

Answer (score -1):

You can not act on `UI`, or Main thread within of another.

This line :

`lbxNumbers.Items.Add(item);`

which is invoked from another thread can cause a trouble. 
The proper way of handling this scenario in WindowsForms would be using of

[Control.Invoke](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zyzhdc6b(v=vs.110).aspx) method.